# I have configure postgresql database to django project but when i run server, nothing happens , just "Watching for file changes with StatReloader"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i want to change my database from sqlite to postgresql but when i run server, nothing happens , no response , just "Watching for file changes with StatReloader"

Comment: did you run the command `migrate` after changing the settings ?

Comment: @ no, i didn't make changes on models , just change settings.py file from sqlite to postgresql

Comment: you still need to generate the tables in postgre, try to run `migrate`

Comment: I have already "migrate" but still no response . nothing happens. just waiting .